# Inline-edit datagrid: currency editing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF datagrid with an editable column that happens to be a decimal datatype, with a currency mask.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to edit this mask, the output result is very bizarre: i.e. if I select the column and type '400' the currency mask fills in $004.00, this is quite undesirable.  How can I remedy this?  I would like for the mask to NOT show up while editing (or at least change the edit so it isn't right-to-left)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to apply the mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out: basically, I had the UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged, so on set it was constantly trying to format my value to a currency, thus messing up the formatting "as you type".  Changed to UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus so setting wouldn't occur until after the focus on the field was lost.